# Filter with field has relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have these models in Django:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Sale(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Sale %s (%i)" % (self.type, self.id)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Unitary_Sale(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)
```

How can I filter to get all books that customer sale?

I tried:

```
units=Unitary_Sale.objects.all()
>>> units=Unitary_Sale.objects.all()
>>> for unit in units:
...    print unit.sale.customer
...    print unit.book,unit.sale.total
...
Sok nara
Khmer Empire (H001) 38.4
Sok nara
killing field (H001) 16

San ta
khmer krom (H001) 20
San ta
Khmer Empire (H001) 20
>>>
```

what I want:

```
  sok nora:56.4 (38.4+18)
  san ta:40 (20+20)
```

Or to dictionary:

```
{sok nora:156.4, san ta:40}

>>> store_resulte = {}
>>> for unit in units:
...    store_resulte[unit.sale.customer] = unit.sale.total
...
>>> print store_resulte

    {<Customer: Sok nara>: Decimal("16"), <Customer: san ta>: Decimal("20")}
```

It should be:

```
{<Customer: Sok nara>: Decimal("56.4"), <Customer: san ta>: Decimal("40")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [aggregation documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

I believe this should do the trick (only with version 1.1 or dev.):

```
Customer.objects.annotate(total=Sum('sale__total'))
```

**EDIT**: You can also define a custom method for the class:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def total_sale(self):
        total = 0
        for s in self.sale_set:
           total += s.total
        return total
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'annotate'

Comment: Which Django version are you using? try to replace `annotate` by `aggregate`.

Comment: It's adapt my question?so what I should applied this to my quiz? :)

Comment: look at my posting.I changed annotate to aggregate it the same error.
for your customer method How can I use it? thanks

Comment: If you define a method in the model Class, it will be available for every Customer instance. It's something like  `Customer.objects.get(name='Sok nara').total_sale()`

Comment: when I  Customer.objects.get(name='Sok nara').total_sale
<bound method Customer.total_sale of <Customer: Mesa>> 
Not any results???

Comment: When I Customer.objects.get(name='Sok nara').total_sale()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "..../models.py", line 118, in total_sale
    for s in self.sale_set:
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable